# db40 - recommendation for file viewer tool

Tags: db4o

Can anyone recommend me a good DB4O file viewer ?

Bonus : Does anyone have a recommendation of a tool that can look at corrupted files (made by db40)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well db4o includes its object manager for [Java](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/object_manager_enterprise.htm) and .[NET](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/net/reference/Content/object_manager_enterprise.htm)

For .NET I've written a [LINQPad driver](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2011/04/linqpad-db4o-driver-feature-overview/). If it is missing a feature just tell me.

For broken databases. Hmm, not sure if there a great tool for that. But I would first check with the integrity check tool. ([Java](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/troubleshoot/corrupt_db.htm), [.NET](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/net/reference/Content/troubleshoot/corrupt_db.htm))

Comment: Thanks. I am using java. I gavve it a shot by downloading framework 4.0 and linqpad and your driver. I tried to open my db40 files ( generated in my java app ) and received myfile.db4 (Error: unable to cast object of type 'DB4Object.Db40.Reflect.Generic.GenericObject to type 'DB4objects.Db4o.ext.Db4oDatabase')). I am guessing it is not possible . Am I right ?